# Is this the hessian bilinear form or $1/2$ of it?

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

Look at:

[image]

the author writes "full hessian", but it's clearly $\frac12\operatorname{hess}r$. Or not?

Other question: why does the author mean by "real harmonic polynomial"? And why it should be equal to the real part of the sum he written?!

Any hint will be appreciated! Many thanks!

**EDIT** Here's a more complete part of my book:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume that $\partial_z\partial_zr=\partial_\overline{z}\partial_\overline{z}r$, in which case summing over repeated indices will give us twice the Hessian, so we take $1/2$ to get the correct value. Also by "real harmonic" I believe the first two sums (summed together) give a harmonic function with values in $\Bbb R$, i.e. a real harmonic function. Note that this supports my first assumption :)

Comment: Many thanks! $r$ is indeed a real function, but how can I prove it's harmonic? It doesn't make sense: $r$ is twice differentiable, how can I derive again? Then: how can I deal with the $dz_i\otimes d\bar z_j$ during the derivation?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, how differentiable is $r$? I imagine that if you assumed $r$ was sufficiently differentiable, then the calculation would come out nicely, also harmonic functions are smooth, so you should be able to differentiate enough

Comment: No , $r$ is only twice differentiable, not "sufficiently". I'm going to edit my post, in order to show you the situation